# Spring security expressions fail if user has multiple authorities

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have 3 controllers annotated with @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority(x)") where x is

```
'ROLE_ADMIN'
'ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_MID'
'ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_MID','ROLE_LOW'
```

Crucial point: If a user has ONE authority, these annotations work just fine. Ex: A user with *only* ROLE_ADMIN can access all methods on all 3. 
*BUT* if a user has some other role as well, e.g. ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_OTHER, then all I get "Access Denied" on across all three controllers.

See this table for what I'm talking about. (hAA=hasAnyAuthority):

```
+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|      Authorities      | hAA('ROLE_ADMIN') | hAA('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_MID') | hAA('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_MID','ROLE_LOW') |
+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| ROLE_ADMIN            | YES               | YES                          | YES                                     |
| ROLE_MID              | NO                | YES                          | YES                                     |
| ROLE_LOW              | NO                | NO                           | YES                                     |
| ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_OTHER | NO                | NO                           | NO                                      |
| ROLE_MID,ROLE_OTHER   | NO                | NO                           | NO                                      |
| ROLE_LOW,ROLE_OTHER   | NO                | NO                           | NO                                      |
+-----------------------+-------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Just to drive the point home, I have a user whose getAuthorites returns (as string) "[ROLE_MID,mid.mid12345]" and all three controllers fail for that user. Shouldn't "hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_MID')" work for him? Why would having "mid.mid12345" cause it to fail?

PS I've tried hasAnyRole as well with the same results.

Answer (score 2):

I figure out that in older versions of Spring Security 4, whole comma-separated list is acceptable without using single-quote for each authority

Example:

```
hasAnyAuthority('AUTHORITY1,AUTHORITY2,AUTHORTIY3')
```

In Spring Security 5, this is not an acceptable list so it should be replaced with

```
hasAnyAuthority('AUTHORITY1', 'AUTHORITY2', 'AUTHORTIY3')
```

Took some time to figure out so I would like to share here

Comment: Not sure about exact Spring Security versions though

Comment: What is the exact Spring Security v5 you have used? I came across the same issue and I think it happened somewhere between 5.4.1 and 5.7.5

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try without single quotes and just comma-separated, take a look to documentation(https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html)

*hasAnyAuthority([authority1,authority2])    Returns true if the current principal has any of the supplied roles (given as a comma-separated list of strings)*

Also I think your roles cannot start with *ROLE_*.

*Returns true if the current principal has any of the supplied roles (given as a comma-separated list of strings). By default if the supplied role does not start with 'ROLE_' it will be added. This can be customized by modifying the defaultRolePrefix on DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.*

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I have a UserDetailsService set up with the sole loadUserByUsername method overridden in order to connect my database entity user, `Customuser`, to Spring Security's `Userdetails.User`.

But my conversion from one to the other was incorrect.

```
INCORRECT

User user = new User(customuser.getUsername(), customuser.getPassword(), AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(customuser.getAuthorityString()));

CORRECT

User user = new User(customuser.getUsername(), customuser.getPassword(), customuser.getAuthoritiesList()); // see below
```

My `Customuser` object stores a comma-separated list of the authorities the user has. When using AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList, it was taking that string, whether it was "ROLE_ADMIN" or "ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_OTHER" and making the entire string ONE authority. The latter of the two above would have been *a single authority* authority of "ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_OTHER". (This explains why users with only one authority were working just fine and any user with mutiple was failing.)

I had to create a custom method within `Customuser` to chop that custom CSV string into individual authorities before creating my UserDetails.User object in loadUserByUsername.

```
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthoritiesList()
{
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(authorityString,",");
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> returnlist = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        returnlist.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(st.nextToken()));
    }
    return returnlist;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else!